# How is the word "coir" pronounced: like /kɔɪɹ/ /kɔɪɚ/ or /kɔɪjɚ/?

Tags: pronunciation

I've been reviewing the General American English pronunciation of the word "coir".  I had previously pronounced it /kwɑɹ/ (rhyming with noir), but understand now that I was wrong.

I've found several different pronunciations of the word:

1. /kɔɪɹ/
2. /kɔɪɚ/
3. /kɔɪjɚ/ - This spelling adapted from the Dictionary of the British English Spelling System by Greg Brooks, which has it as /kɔɪjə/ in British English.  Screenshot attached.

From listening to YouTube videos, it sounds like Option 2 (/kɔɪɚ/) most closely matches what Americans say.  (Although my previous mispronunciation of /kwɑɹ/ is also very common.)  I can't hear the explicit yod in Option 3, but perhaps it's just me.

How do you pronounce the word, "coir"?

[image]

Comment: I think those three IPA pronunciations you give are all different represntation of the same underlying pronunciation, where *coir* rhymes with *foyer*.

Comment: @PeterShor I think a better example would be *lawyer*. *Foyer* can also be pronounced "foi-ay" or even "fwah-yay" in imitation of French.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw: And *lawyer* can be pronounced *law-yer* and not *loy-er*. So maybe a good example is *employer*.

Comment: 'coir' is not a common word in English, it's orthography is not typical English (it's very typical French orthography, but not a common word there either). That said, if it is borrowed from Tamil (for coconut fiber) then it probably does rhyme with 'foyer' (either the American or British pronunciation)

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw In the UK "foyer" is almost always pronounced in the French manner, foy-ay as you say. I've never heard anyone say fwah-yah, although I've not heard our current PM try to say it. When it come to "coir" I've only ever heard it pronounced _coy-er_. Nothing like the British pronunciation of "foyer "at all.

Comment: @BoldBen I looked it up in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary. I suppose there are few people out there who wanna imitate as accurately as possibly. For example, "fawlks vahgen" is a valid pronunciation, albeit rare, along with the more common "vokes waggen".

Comment: @BoldBen I've generally heared "foy-er", and considered "foy-ay" to be use of French pronunciation for pretentiousness.

Comment: @Barmar I assume that you're American. "Foy-er" would mark you out as poorly educated in the UK.

Comment: Both LPD and CED give /kɔɪr/

Comment: In American English, it sounds like coy-er: /ˈkɔɪər/.

Comment: Coir is a Malayalam word. (Malayalam is the language of a small state in South India). It refers to the fiber from coconuts, which is used for making ropes, doormats, mattresses etc.  See this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=coir&sxsrf=ALeKk02dXcyjswKMNHyjcvYQog3MIHeZFA:1625704465463&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6rLGJndLxAhVczzgGHYlsBsAQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1024&bih=678;  Its pronunciation resembles what Tinfoil Hat commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between /kɔɪɚ/ and /kɔɪjɚ/ is purely one of notation. /ɔɪ/ already ends in a glide, though this becomes much more prominent when it precedes another vowel sound; [Geoff Lindsey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtnlGH055TA) covers how this explains the ability of /ɔɪ/ to occur before another vowel without creating hiatus.

Dictionaries seem to disagree about whether this is pronounced as a single syllable /kɔɪɹ/ or as two syllables /kɔɪ.ɚ/; [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/coir) provides the former but [OxfordLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/coir) provides the latter. I suspect that both are found but that /kɔɪ.ɚ/ is more common, as your investigation on YouTube shows.